How can I delete data with shiny input_action_button?
I have recently started working with Shiny Python and got stuck at some point.
from pathlib import Path

from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, render, ui


ui.page_opts(title="Stock explorer", fillable=True)

with ui.sidebar():
    ui.input_text("data_one","Insert Number",placeholder="Insert Number 1")
    ui.input_text("data_two","Insert Number",placeholder="Insert Number 2")
    ui.input_action_button("add_data", "Add Data", class_="btn-primary")
    ui.input_action_button("delete_data", "Delete Data", class_= "btn-danger")


with ui.layout_column_wrap(fill=False):
    with ui.value_box():
        "Number One"

        @render.ui
        def data_1():
            return f"{get_data_one()}"

    with ui.value_box():
        "Number 2"

        @render.ui
        def data_2():
            return f"{get_data_two()}"


ui.include_css(Path(__file__).parent / "styles.css")


@reactive.calc
@reactive.event(input.add_data, ignore_none=False)
def get_data_one():
    return input.data_one()

@reactive.calc
@reactive.event(input.add_data, ignore_none=False)
def get_data_two():
    return input.data_two()

@reactive.calc
def data_delete():
    pass

I am stuck as to how I can update the ui.value_box as empty while pressing the Delete Data button. In the reference page https://shiny.posit.co/py/api/express/ I can see I would be able to update inputs and layout, but not able to get how to update the value_box.
I have kept the data_delete() function to be pass as of now.
Any feedback or suggestions will help.

Give this a shot.
You want to choose to set the output to match the input values or to be None. You can set a reactive.Value to whatever you want. That decision is a side effect (a reactive.effect) of clicking one of the buttons (the reactive.event()). This codes both paths and lets the user pick. The data_1 and data_2 functions update everytime a reactive value inside them is set to a new value.
Use parentheses as in value_one() to return a value, no need for a f-strings.
reactive.calc is for when you want to return a value.
reactive.effect is for other side effects without a return value.
from pathlib import Path

from shiny import reactive
from shiny.express import input, render, ui



with ui.sidebar():
    ui.input_text("data_one","Insert Number",placeholder="Insert Number 1")
    ui.input_text("data_two","Insert Number",placeholder="Insert Number 2")
    ui.input_action_button("add_data", "Add Data", class_="btn-primary")
    ui.input_action_button("delete_data", "Delete Data", class_= "btn-danger")

with ui.layout_column_wrap(fill=False):
    with ui.value_box():
        "Number One"

        @render.ui
        def data_1():
            return value_one()

    with ui.value_box():
        "Number 2"

        @render.ui
        def data_2():
            return value_two()

value_one = reactive.Value()
value_two = reactive.Value()

@reactive.effect
@reactive.event(input.add_data)
def _():
    value_one.set(input.data_one())
    value_two.set(input.data_two())


@reactive.effect
@reactive.event(input.delete_data)
def _():
    value_one.set(None)
    value_two.set(None)

